# Error: .dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application on Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit

Tags: windows, service

I would like to get some help, I'm getting this error in the middle of a running windows service. The details are:

1. I have used Safenet 5 jars and dlls in my java web application which is developed using Netbeans. And I have installed Safenet 5 PTK.
2. I have created an exe using Advanced Installer. I got it installed successfully in 64-bit machine.
3. The service is started without any error.
4. My program will invoke Safenet dll during the execution of a particular part.
5. At that point I'm getting this error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\a\b\c\lib\xxx.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

I have googled a lot for this. I have 64-bit jdk and I gave that in the system path as well. I have MicroSoft Visual C++ installed. Don't know why it is coming.

It would be grateful if someone help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance..